# Get distinct elements from java string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string array as below.

```
String [] exmp = {"Example ExamPle", "Example"};
```

I want to get distinct element from the above array irrespective of character case.

I need to get the below output for above array.
"Example"

I have tried with the following code.

```
LinkedHashSet<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

String [] exmp = {"Example ExamPle", "Example"};

for(String s : exmp) {

String unqWrds = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

set.add(unqWrds);

}
```

But currently I am getting entire string getting added to set due to case difference 
"Example ExamPle", "Example"

Could you please advise here.

Comment: Are you asking how to ignore the case difference? Because the example you chose is problematic. I don’t understand how you define distinct . If it was “example example example” would it still be the same?

Comment: There are two distinct elements in the array. Now if the array was `{"Example", "ExamPle", "Example"}`, there would be one distinct value when you ignore case.

Comment: And is “a a a a” the same as “a a a”? What’s the logic

Comment: I am asking how can I do equalIgnorecase here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the sample code in the question, you want to split the strings on whitespace, even though you never said that in the question.

You then try to use `distinct()`, but that will unfortunately not work, because `distinct()` doesn't take a `Comparator`, so it cannot compare case-insensitively.

To get your desired result:

```
// Using loops
public static Set<String> distinctWords(String... input) {
    Set<String> distinct = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    for (String s : input)
        for (String word : s.trim().split("\\s+"))
            distinct.add(word);
    return distinct;
}
```

```
// Using streams
public static Set<String> distinctWords(String... input) {
    return Stream.of(input)
            .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("\\s+")))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)));
}
```

The `TreeSet` will keep the capitalization of the first word seen, and will sort the words, so the result of calling with `{"Example ExamPle", "example"}` is the desired result `[Example]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
String unqWrds = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")).reduce("", (x, y) -> x.toUpperCase().contains(y.toUpperCase()) ? x : x + " " + y);
```

Answer (score 0):

The ignore case part can be done like this:

```
String unqWrds = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+")).map(String::toLowerCase).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```